# Is $f:\Bbb R^*\to\Bbb R^+: x\mapsto\lvert x\rvert$ homomorphic, and what is its kernel?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

> Let $\Bbb R^*$ be the group of real numbers under multiplication (number $0$ is not in $ \Bbb R^*$) and $\Bbb R^+$ be the group of positive real numbers under multiplication. Define $f:\Bbb R^*\to\Bbb R^+: x\mapsto\lvert x\rvert$.
>
> Is $f$ a group homomorphism?

For this, we need to show that $f(ab)=f(a)\,f(b)$.

$$\lvert xy\rvert=\lvert x\rvert\lvert y\rvert$$

This would lead to both $x$ and $y$ being positive numbers. Therefore they will be equal under multiplication. Therefore $f$ is a group homomorphism.

> Find the kernel of $f$.

What can you conclude in this question by using the fundamental homomorphism theorem?

Comment: Would the Kernel of this be 1 Since $f(1)= |1|=e$?

Comment: This only shows that $1 \in ker(f)$. However, there are other elements of $ker(f)$, like $-1$. Is this all of the elements of $ker(f)$?

Answer (score 3):

For $x, y\in(\mathbb R^*, \cdot)$, by definition of absolute value function,  $f(x\cdot y)=|x\cdot y|=|x|\cdot|y|$ , hence $f$ is a homomorphism.

$\begin{align}\text{kernel }f &=\{x\in\mathbb R\colon f(x)=1\}\\&=\{x\in\mathbb R\colon |x|=1\}\\&=\{x=\pm 1\}\end{align}$

$f$ is surjective because for any positive real $x$, it is the absolute value of exactly two (nonzero) real numbers : $\pm x$.

Fundamental homomorphism theorem ensures $(\mathbb R^*, \cdot)/\{\pm 1\}\cong (\mathbb R^+, \cdot)$

Comment: It's false that $\mathbb R^\times \cong \mathbb R^+$. Indeed, $-1$ is an element of order 2 in $\mathbb R^\times$ but there are no elements of order 2 in $\mathbb R^+$. I think you mean $\mathbb R^\times / \{1, -1\} \cong \mathbb R^+$.

Comment: @paul blart math cop sorry for the typo! edited : )

Comment: Use `\cdot` not `.`